# Source code changes but not effect in Maven war

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I have a strange problem in Eclipse.When i change in Java files like Controller and  clean install maven.The controller as it is.There is no change in war.I delete all controllers but still my project working.I tried my methods like check build automtically,clear metadeta in workspace.Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the source code and do `mvn clean install` you will get the newly compiled source code in the war. You probably made some other error like

- Changing the code of the wrong project.
- Changing code that is never called or does not affect the behaviour of the war.
- Not deploying or starting the new war, but some old version.

Comment: Sir I already check this problem.I am facing this problem from 3 days and I Check code and also delete all repository in .m2 folder but my problem as it is

Comment: Then install a command line Maven and try to build on the command line. It is possible that this is a strange Eclipse error, but I still think that it is more likely that you made some other, unrelated error.

Comment: I already try this so many times but problem is not solved.Please help me

Comment: If you install Maven (say 3.5.4), go to the project directory and run "mvn clean install", Maven should either throw an error or build from the source that is in the project directory under src/main/java.It is important that you do all these steps purely on the command line.

Comment: I tried again and i delete one controller means a java file in my project then "mvn clean install" in command line. In target/classes folder that file doesnt exist and in traget/{war name}/WEB-INF/classes that file exist.it is a strange problem

Comment: Maybe you have some kind of source code or byte code generation?